# C: client program reports SSL Certificate verify failed error with localCA

Tags: c, linux, ssl, openssl, rhel

I am writing a simple TLS client/server program to securely communicate over the network. Initially I am building and running both the client and server on the same machine running RHEL 8.2.

First, I am using custom self signned ssl certificate and key for my programs. I have placed the rootCA.crt (my custom CA certificate in /root/CA/rootCA.crt). Also copied the rootCA.pem to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ and executed `update-ca-trust enable` then `update-ca-trust extract` to install the certificate to the system. (Not sure if I need to reboot the system for it to take effect.)

Initially, the client and server were able to communicate usint TLS untill I added the certificate validation part of the code on the client side.

Certificate Verification snippet:

```
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* Create new context */
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }

    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);

    SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx, 4);

    const long flags = SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 |
                        SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 |
                        SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 |
                        SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1 |
                        SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION;
    SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, flags);

    if(SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, NULL, 
                "/root/CA/") == 0){
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }

ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      /* create new SSL connection state */
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);    /* attach the socket descriptor */
    if ( SSL_connect(ssl) == FAIL )   /* perform the connection */
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    else
    {

        sprintf(acClientRequest, "%s", cpRequestMessage);   /* construct reply */
        printf("\n\nConnected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_ciphe

}
```

when I run the server and client programs I see the following error messafe =>

Onclient:
140736372886336:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1915:

On Server:
140736022137664:error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1543:SSL alert number 48

Not sure, what is going wrong with the certificate validation process. Can anyone suggest me how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Just copying your `rootCA.crt` file into `/root/CA/` is not enough.

`SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` explicitly states that the files in this directory have to use a specific format:

> If CApath is not NULL, it points to a directory containing CA
> certificates in PEM format. The files each contain one CA certificate.
> The files are looked up by the CA subject name hash value, which must
> hence be available. If more than one CA certificate with the same name
> hash value exist, the extension must be different (e.g. 9d66eef0.0,
> 9d66eef0.1 etc). The search is performed in the ordering of the
> extension number, regardless of other properties of the certificates.
> Use the c_rehash utility to create the necessary links.

Therefore make sure your `rootCa.crt` is in PEM format. And then generate the required hash and rename it accordingly. The following command generates the hashvalue. Rename the file to `<hashvalue>.0`.

```
openssl x509 -inform PEM -subject_hash_old -in rootCa.crt | head -1
```

If your code then still does not work I would first test if your code works at all. For doing so change the server URL to a real server that sues an HTTPS certificate that is already trusted on your system.

Comment: I attempted with renaming the CA.crt to <hashvalue>.0 in  the same directory (/root/CA/). But, the issue persists... I also tried connecting to google.com port:443 and see the same issue there as well. Seems like there is some issue with my client code. If I comment out the `SSL_CTX_set_verify`, `SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth` and `SSL_CTX_load_verify_location` fumctions in the client code, I am able to see the connection happening normally to both server program and google.com:443. Could you tell me how to correctly verify the received server certificate?

Comment: Finaly was able to fix the issue. Changed the `SSL_CTX_load_verify_location()`function call to point to the rootCA certificate directly instead of to the directory containing the certificate. Like: `
    if(SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "/root/CA/01c81d11.0", NULL) <= 0){
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
` After the change, the client and server are able to communicate again without errors. Also checked by changing the server key and certificate to unsigned ones, I see the client program complaining about untrusted certifiate received froem the server.